# Get the path of the file stored in the local memory and Play 1 video in full screen mode (landscape) by Media Element

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

I have some difficulties not know how to solve, expect people to help!

1. Can I get the path of the file stored in the local memory of WP8 or not?
2. How to play 1 video in full screen mode (landscape) by Media Element

Answer (score 0):

1. No. For MediaLibrary you can get song's collection which you can play using mediaplayer.
2. This is how you can play video:

   ```
   MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
                       mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = Uri; //Uri will be your video Uri
                       mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
                       mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
                       mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;
                       mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
   ```